# How to Scroll in container

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am using a container in Ext.js 3.2 in following way

```
con = new Ext.Container( {
autoScroll: true,
...
```

There is a list in the container. But I find that I can't scroll the container. Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much

Comment: what layout are you using in the container?